# Check if Element is last element in Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the current element in a `.each` loop is the last element in a selection?

I have tried it with the following code:

```
$('#order').find('.xyz').find('input[id ^="order"]').not('[id $="_zyx"]').each(function (index, element) {
    var isLast = ($(element) == $('#order').find('.xyz').find('input[id ^="order"]').not('[id $="_zyx"]').last());
});
```

With the query I am getting three elements. And I want to select the last element of this selection for further use.

In order to determine which element is the right one I have tested it with the code above but I am getting `false` for `isLast` for the last element where it should be `true`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use Jquery for this.
Use the length of your elements and the index of your loop.

```
var elements = $('#order').find('.xyz').find('input[id ^="order"]').not('[id $="_zyx"]');

elements.each(function (index, element) {
    var isLast = (index+1) === elements.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your HTML, but you should just be able to use the last selector:
https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: my used HTML is not relevant for this. I gave all the required informations. Which are the query and the number of returned elements.

Comment: Your jQuery looks quite complex and could probably be simplified significantly if we could see the HTML.